# Point-of-Sales in C Language

Tags: c

I am very new here so I still don't know how this site works but anyways, I need help!

I'm a total beginner in c programming (actually in programming) and I'm making a simple point-of-sales program. Here's the code I've made so far...

```
#include <stdio.h>

int code, qty, nxt;
float price, amt, total, cash, change; 
char next, ans;

void main()
{
do {
    system("cls");
    // Display all available products
    printf("     MARGIE'S SARI-SARI STORE");
    printf("\n\n      --AVAILABLE PRODUCTS-- ");
    printf("\n = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = \n\n");
    printf("[1] Eggs\t\tPhp 9.00\n");
    printf("[2] Noodles\t\tPhp 10.00\n");
    printf("[3] Sardine\t\tPhp 20.00\n");
    printf("\n = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = \n");

    do {
        printf("\nProduct\t\t: ");
        scanf("%d", &code);
        printf("Quantity\t: ");
        scanf("%d", &qty);

        switch (code)
        {
            case 1:
                price = 9.00;
            break;
            case 2:
                price = 10.00;
            break;
            case 3:
                price = 20.00;
            break;
            default: printf("Invalid input!"); break;
        }

        // Compute the amount for each product
        amt = price * qty;
        printf("Amount\t\t: %.2f", amt);

        // Compute total amount for all purchase
        total = total + amt;
        
        printf("\nNext? Enter any number (0 to exit): ");
        scanf("%d", &nxt);
    } while (nxt!=0);

    printf("\n = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = \n");
    printf("TOTAL\t\t: %.2f", total);
    printf("\n = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = \n");

    do {
        // Input cash payment, credit not allowed
        printf("\nCash\t\t: ");
        scanf("%f", &cash);

        // Compute amount change
        change = cash - total;
        printf("Change\t\t: %.2f", change);
    } while (cash<total);
    
    printf("\n\nNext Transaction? [y/n]: ");
    ans = getch();
    
} while (ans=='y' || ans=='Y');
}
```

Here is the output:

```
     MARGIE'S SARI-SARI STORE      

      --AVAILABLE PRODUCTS--       
 = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = 

[1] Eggs                Php 9.00   
[2] Noodles             Php 10.00  
[3] Sardine             Php 20.00  

 = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = 

Product         : 1
Quantity        : 1
Amount          : 9.00
Next? Enter any number (0 to exit): 0

 = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = 
TOTAL           : 9.00
 = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = =

Cash            : 10
Change          : 1.00

Next Transaction? [y/n]: y     
     
     MARGIE'S SARI-SARI STORE

      --AVAILABLE PRODUCTS--
 = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = =

[1] Eggs                Php 9.00
[2] Noodles             Php 10.00
[3] Sardine             Php 20.00

 = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = =

Product         : 2
Quantity        : 2
Amount          : 20.00
Next? Enter any number (0 to exit): 1

Product         : 3
Quantity        : 2
Amount          : 40.00
Next? Enter any number (0 to exit): 0

 = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = =
TOTAL           : 69.00
 = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = =

Cash            : 100
Change          : 31.00

Next Transaction? [y/n]: n
```

As you can see, I'm having problem with the total because it adds the previous total computed from the previous transaction. How do I clear the previous computation in total so that if I want to run it again the previous total would not add to the new one?
Please feel free to run this if you have a compiler at hand. Thankss

Comment: It's not clear what the issue is. Please give the exact input, expected result and actual result.

Comment: hello sir, the input was the products and quantity specified in the switch statements. Also, the cash to pay. The outputs were the total and change. My problem is whenever I try to enter 'y' in the printf("\n\nNext Transaction? [y/n]: "); the program will run but it will add the previous total to the new total.

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70847389/edit) the post to show the **exact** input and output. That is, copy it directly from your terminal into the post. Then type in what the output is expected to be instead.

Comment: Just _look_ at what you do with `total`. You add to it (`total = total + amt`), and you compare it (`cash<total`), but you never reset it to zero. So why would you expect it to become zero? You know exactly what you want to do ("clear the previous computation in total"), so _do_ it: write `total = 0;` somewhere appropriate.

Comment: ohh yeah that works, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `total=0` after `system("cls");`